# Is it OK to ask questions about database design on Programmers?

Tags: discussion, site-rec

I have asked "[Why do famous CMSes uss string flags in the database instead of integers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/284530/57759)" question here. After asking it (and receiving an answer) I realized that Database Administrators has [`database-design`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-design) tag and I have found [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216770/189165).

My question is currently +2 upvoted, but it also contains two close votes. And I wonder, if these are because someone just didn't like my question or maybe because I asked it in the wrong place and I should rather go to Database Designers with next questions of this kind?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions about database design are on topic.

However, the close votes aren't because your question is about database design, but because you are asking for speculation on what a small handful of people did coincidentally, who may have been doing it for different reasons. As a result, the close votes are for "primarily opinion based".